# flutter for android Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'

Tags: flutter, gradle

I used to have the same project running. For some reason I cannot figure out I can no more compile the android version:

```
$ flutter doctor                                                                                           1 
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.2, on macOS 14.0 23A344 darwin-arm64, locale en-ES)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2023.2.5)
[✓] Connected device (4 available)
[✓] Network resources

• No issues found!
```

```
 $ jenv versions                                                                                              
  system
  17.0
  17.0.5
  17.0.6
  21
  21.0
  21.0.1
* temurin64-21.0.1
```

```
flutter run 
 $ flutter run                                                                                                
Using hardware rendering with device sdk gphone64 arm64. If you notice graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering
with "--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 arm64 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Multiple build operations failed.
      java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /Users/xxx/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/e187d20b7adb494ecad124a62ab6ca3e/results.bin
      java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /Users/xxx/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/f85c31d78373eceb5c95e6d87927ef10/results.bin

...

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                              3.4s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

My android/build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'
        // START: FlutterFire Configuration
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.1'
        // END: FlutterFire Configuration
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and my android/app/build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
// START: FlutterFire Configuration
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
// END: FlutterFire Configuration
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 34
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "xxx"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        // minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        minSdkVersion 21
        multiDexEnabled true
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "pl.leancode.patrol.PatrolJUnitRunner"
        testInstrumentationRunnerArguments clearPackageData: "true"
    }

    testOptions {
        execution "ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

//    buildTypes {
//        release {
//            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
//            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
//            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
//        }
//    }

}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    androidTestUtil "androidx.test:orchestrator:1.4.2"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.5'
}
```

```
name: xxx
description: xxx
# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+58

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.1.0 <4.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  supabase_flutter: ^1.7.0
  flutter_dotenv: ^5.0.2
  table_calendar: ^3.0.0
  syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer: ^22.2.12
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.1
  firebase_core: ^2.10.0
  firebase_messaging: ^14.4.1
  mocktail: ^1.0.0
  week_of_year: ^2.0.0
  supabase_auth_ui: ^0.2.1
  dart_dotenv: ^1.0.1
  firebase_crashlytics: ^3.3.5
  event_bus: ^2.0.0
  url_launcher: ^6.1.14
  package_info: ^2.0.2
  flutter_local_notifications: ^15.1.1
  jwt_decoder: ^2.0.1
  pub_semver: ^2.1.4
  flutter_markdown: ^0.6.18+2
  timezone: ^0.9.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  integration_test:
    sdk: flutter
  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
  patrol: ^2.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/.local.env
    - assets/.test.env
    - assets/.prod.env
    - assets/.staging.env
    - assets/images/logo.png
    - assets/images/logo-mascota.png
  # - assets/test.pdf
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
flutter_launcher_icons:
  android: true
  ios: true
  image_path_android: "assets/images/logo_android.png"
  adaptive_icon_background: "#ffffff"
  adaptive_icon_foreground: "assets/images/logo_android.png"
  image_path_ios: "assets/images/logo_ios.png"

patrol:
  app_name: xxxx
  android:
    package_name: xxx
  ios:
    bundle_id: xxx
```

I tried to create a project from scratch and it does run.